# How can I set 2 data values with a select input?

Tags: vuejs2

I am using VueJS to get data from my Laravel API. It's an array with objects. I have a select element and I am using v-for on the option element. v-model is on the select element.

I want to set 2 data properties when I select on of the option, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have tried setting up computed properties, but it does not work or I am doing it wrong.

Template:

```
<div class="col-4">
     <label for="name">Customer</label>

     <select class="form-control" v-model="form.customer">
          <option disabled value>Select the Customer</option>
          <option v-for="customer in customers" :key="customer.id">{{ 
                  customer.customer }}</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Data:

```
data: () => {
    return {
      customers: [],
      form: {
        customer: "",
        color: "#ff8080",
        job: "",
        start_date: "",
        deadline_date: "",
        delivery_date: "",
        boilermaker: ""
      }
    };
  },
```

I want to set form.color when I select the customer name from the options list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't return two parameters, the only way I know is to catch @change event and then get the desired value from your array :

```
<div class="col-4">
     <label for="name">Customer</label>

     <select class="form-control" v-model="form.customer" 
      @change="setColor($event.target.value)"
      >
          <option disabled value>Select the Customer</option>
          <option v-for="customer in customers" :key="customer.id">{{ 
                  customer.customer }}</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

and under methods:

```
methods:{

   setColor(customerName){
    this.from.color =   this.customers.find(x=>x.customer===customerName).color
},

}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. You do have a typo, but this is what I needed.